# Discord.js stream mpeg audio stream into voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, audio-streaming, mpeg

I want to stream a mpeg audio stream (MIME type: `audio/mpeg`) from an URL (specifically https://s1-sjc.liveatc.net/kjfk_atis) constantly into one of the voice channels on my Discord server using a bot.

I am using the `discord.js` nodejs module which handles the discord API in an object-orieentated fashion. I have already created a bot account and done the basic "Ping!Pong!" test to make sure my code is working.

I have no idea how mpeg audio stream or Discord voice channel API works nor found anyone with experience doing this.

I was going for a cheap approach that simply replies the URL to the user in plain text in a text channel. But I feel that is unaccpetable.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('heregoesmybottoken');
```

The finished result should connect to a voice channel and start playing/streaming audio from URL https://s1-sjc.liveatc.net/kjfk_atis once it is started.

---

**EDIT**

To me, the solution of *truncating the audio stream, writing it to disk, then reading it off the disk* is **unacceptable** because that causes massive I/O stress.

As nobody has given an answered yet, I have done some investigation myself and found that the technique used to stream audio at https://s1-sjc.liveatc.net/kjfk_atis is different to those of video streaming: it is **not chunked**, but instead a constant HTTPS request containing what presumably is raw PCM data.

```js
const request = require('request');
const fs = require("fs");
request('https://s1-sjc.liveatc.net/kjfk_atis').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('atis.mp3'));
```

I wrote this code to download the stream and indeed NodeJS started **continuously writing** to `atis.mp3` until I press `Ctrl+C`. The file does contain the audio and is open-able by Windows Media Player.

So now I just need to find out a way to redirect this stream to discord.js, and hopefully node-opus will automatically convert the stream to the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still have no idea what exactly is going on. But after many trial and errors, found this does the job.

```js
var voice, player;

// To join channel
client.channels.get("channelid").join()
    .then((connection) => {voice = connection});

// To stream audio
player = voice.playArbitraryInput("https://s1-sjc.liveatc.net/kjfk_atis");

// To stop
player.end();
```

I'm just gonna leave this here for future references. Feel free to post some explainations.

Comment: Got a link to the documentation for the join method? Having trouble finding it.